# Sanitizing non-English letters to use safely in URLs

Tags: c#, .net, url, escaping

What is the best way, in .NET, to create *safe* URLs from titles of posts?
For example, I may have a post "test wıth non enğlİşh çharaçters" and I want to turn this into a URL safe form while still maintaining the readability purpose of the title being URL, such as, "test-with-non-english-characters", and I will use them as http://mysite/blog/5/test-with-non-english-characters I can just iterate over the string characters and either leave ALL letters as they are (not safe to use in URLs), or wipe out all non-English characters and turn them into an underscore etc. (breaks the purpose of readability, as posts will/may be in non English languages). I'm sure that there's a method for converting `ş` to `s` and `Ğ` to `G` etc. just like in an accent insensitive search query in SQL server.

Comment: This is probably a losing battle. What lowercase letters does ڟﻌ▓░♀☺╩ۆ correspond to?

Comment: they would be removed. anything that doesn't have an accent insensitive mapping to a letter in the English alphabet would obviously be removed, I don't think I need to say that explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison/368850#368850) to another question to remove accents from a string.

Note that this doesn't completely solve the problem. For example, Asian ideograms or non latin letters will not be transliterated to english (latin) letters using this code.

Comment: for now, just latin accent removal is enough for me. i didn't know about the `Normalize` method, i think it will work for me..