# Sanitize Foreign Characters / Accents From URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-4.0

I need to write a server side function to sanitize URL encoded strings.

Example querystring:

```
FirstName=John&LastName=B%F3th&Address=San+Endre+%FAt+12%2F14
```

When I pass that through `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` I get:

```
FirstName=John&LastName=B�th&Address=San Endre �t 12/14
```

The function from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/368850/585552) is looks perfect but it expects decoded strings that already have accents:

```
RemoveDiacritics('Bóth`) ==> 'Both';
RemoveDiacritics('San Endre út 12/14`) ==> 'San Endre ut 12/14';
```

How can I decode the URL without getting all these `�` characters?

I cannot do anything client side or change the way they come into my function.

Comment: This looks like a fail at the caller... do you control the client application?

Comment: @MarcGravell no, unfortunately I don't have control over that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the arguments already put forth; however, if you’re always receiving your encoded strings from the same client, then you may match their encoding. In this case, they appear to be using [ISO/IEC 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), informally known as **Latin-1**, which is one of the most popular 8-bit character set in use. You can decode ISO/IEC 8859-1 using the following code (which will correctly decode the sample string you provided):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedInput, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

MSDN guarantees that the above code page will be natively supported by the .NET Framework, regardless of the underlying platform; refer to the table of supported encodings for the [Encoding Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

UrlDecode expects UTF-8 for its input, where each character larger than \u007F is encoded as at least 2 bytes. So the correct string (if the character is \u00F3, ó) would have contained `%C3%B3`, not `%F3`.

If the strings arrive the way you get them, I'm not sure there's much you can do. Not with the standard libraries, that is.

By the way, stripping accents from foreign characters is OK, but I wouldn't call it "sanitizing".

Comment: Do you know what type of encoding `B%F3th` is called? Maybe I could try to find a conversion function?

Comment: Well, it's more than likely `Windows-1252`, so you could try to find a decoding routine that uses that.

Answer (score 1):

%F3 and %FA are not in UTF8 nor ASCII encoding. It looks like client side code encodes string in current page's locale.

Depending on your needs you can either simply strip out all characters above 127, or figure out how to properly decode incoming Url (I don't think built in function exist to handle it as is).

I would copy characters into a byte array (including manually decoded %-encoded ones) and use correct Encoding to convert it to string (using Encoding.GetString - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx) .

Comment: to be fair, the existing decode methods do "properly decode" an incoming url... as long as the incoming url meets the specification...

Comment: @Mark Gravell, good point. I used "properly" as "the way it would work for this case", not "the way it should be done".