# Expression predicates with field name with a ToUpper

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I have this code :

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreatePredicate<T>(string typeSearch, string searchField, string stringToSearch)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, searchField),
            "Contains", null,
            Expression.Constant(stringToSearch.ToUpper())), parameter);

    return predicate;
}
```

the result is : `{Param_0 => Param_0.Username.Contains("MX")}`

But I'd like this : `{Param_0 => Param_0.Username.ToUpper().Contains("MX")}`

Thanks,

Comment: As a side-note: You should specify `InvariantCulture` for your `ToUpper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreatePredicate<T>(string typeSearch, string searchField, string stringToSearch)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Call(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, searchField), "ToUpper", null),
            "Contains", null,
            Expression.Constant(stringToSearch.ToUpper())), parameter);

    return predicate;
}
```

Comment: Bonus. I have some string with letters with an accent "é,è, ...". Is there a way to treat 'é' as 'e' ?

Comment: You'll have to look into `CultureInfo culture` parameter of `ToUpper`.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Begin by writing normal, not generated code, which does what you want, *then* convert it to expression.

Comment: when I do a search on "élève" (student in English) and I do a search contains with "eve", I have no result but I have a result with "ève". I'd like if I search with "ève" or "eve" get "élève" as result. I don't want to consider the accent in the search

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison

Comment: I saw that but I don't want remove or change my list, I'd like, if possible, add "Culture Info" to the ToUpper in the ExpressionCall and avoid the loop

Comment: Either way that has nothing with this question. Please close this one and open another.