# allow accented characters to be searchable?

Tags: c#, .net, string, cultureinfo, string-comparison

SOLVED:

I used the following code:

```
var compareinfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo;
var index = compareinfo.IndexOf(strA, strB, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
return index > -1;
```

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

I have a public Kiosk application where users use it to search for a place of interest. Say I have a shop name with the Café word. The kiosk only allows input of English alphabets through an on-screen keyboard. The problem is when I type in Cafe(without the accented é) the search is not valid because the user could not input the character é. I want the application to allow the normal e to be searchable to all accented e and likewise for all other respective characters. How can i do that?

EDIT:
the shop name is "Bruce Café" and i search for "cafe" and it should show in my search results.

using

```
string.Compare("Bruce Café", "cafe", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)
```

returns -1

and

```
string.Compare("Ben-Gurion University (BGU)", "cafe", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace)
```

also returns -1

which i don't know why is it so...

Comment: Please include your "search" code.

Comment: Search from list of strings? DB? Lucene.Net?

Comment: Can you share your search code?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in code:

```
string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

and if you're doing this in T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE
   ColumnName COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI Like '%cafe%' COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AI
```

Comment: how can i search using string.indexof functionaliy also?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7zs7dcf.aspx

Comment: IndexOf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126863/c-sharp-indexof-ignorecase-special-chars

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing your own string comparisons, then you can ignore the accents by specifying [CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to one of the string comparison methods that accepts a CompareOptions parameter, for example [this String.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190529%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)