# C# IndexOf IgnoreCase Special Chars

Tags: c#

How can I do a indexOf Case Insensite with special chars?
I need to search for the word "benefícios", and I want IndexOf to find it even if I don't use the special char on "i"

This way I can't find it:

```
string str = "candidatar-se a benefícios";
string word = "beneficio";
str.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

But with this one I can:

```
string str = "candidatar-se a benefícios exclusivos";
string word = "benefício";
str.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Thanks

Comment: Convert the special characters in the source string to your desired charset (ASCII?) *before* searching with `IndexOf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `CompareInfo` of the relevant culture and use `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace`:

```
string str = "candidatar-se a benefícios";
string word = "beneficio";

var compareInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo;
compareInfo.IndexOf(str, word, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace);
```

You can also combine other compare options - if you wanted to ignore case as well, for example, use `CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase`.

The documentation for [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7zs7dcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [CompareOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) may be of some help.

Comment: See the notes below the code re combining `CompareOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

The second answer seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can have it two ways:

either you use CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory for diacritic marks:

```
static string RemoveDiacritics(string text) 
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in normalizedString)
    {
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
```

}

or you use the UnidecodeSharpFork https://bitbucket.org/DimaStefantsov/unidecodesharpfork

```
   var result = "Test æ".Unidecode();
   Console.WriteLine(result) // Prints Test ae
```