# Find string in text with linq regardless of case or culture

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

I have a search textbox that searches the given text in all the news from the database. So I have this:

```
List<NewsTranslation> newsTranslations = GetByLanguage(GlobalBL.CultureLanguage);
return newsTranslations.Where(
            e =>
            e.NewsContent.Contains(searchText) || e.NewsDescription.Contains(searchText) ||
            e.NewsTitle.Contains(searchText)).ToList();
```

which works fine, but I would need it not to consider case or accents on letters.

Thanks

Comment: Now, are you sure you don't want to push that searching to the database instead of to an iteration in C#? If you have a lot of news performance would take a pretty big hit

Answer (score 1):

This comparator:

```
string.Compare(searchText, e, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

will do the trick. You can include this in your LINQ query where it will of course return 0 when the two arguments are equivalent.