# How to search list with diacritics, when base character is entered?

Tags: c#, list, search, diacritics

I'm writing a small app using VS Express 2013 and C# for Windows Phone 8.1:

Using an AutoSuggestBox tool, I'd like the user's input compare with a List of strings, however the strings in list contain accented characters, like "č,š,ť" and I want to show the user even the results containing "č" when he types "c". How can I do that?

What I have:

```
var resultList = SuggestionsList.Where(s => s.Contains(suggestions.Text));
suggestions.ItemsSource = resultList;
```

Where "SuggestionsList" is the original list of strings and "suggestions" is the name of the autosuggestbox.

Thank you.

Comment: Thats a tough one, I would expect that you would have to reform suggestions.text with the accented variants and re-perform the search for each.

Comment: Would you like to find "đ" if "dj" (as in Djokovic) is entered? If yes then you may need to invent your own `Contains` function that reduces all suggestion words to not only their diacritic-free variants, but also accounts for special cases that have nothing to do with diacritics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RegEx. So if your user is searching for "cat", you could look for something like "[cč]at". Only some of the English language letters have accented variants, so you could make a static list of those and easily construct a RegEx based on the input.

Another, technically more sound approach has been discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison).

### RegEx Example

Suppose your input string is "cat" and you want to search for all variants of the letter "c". As a first step you'll construct your RegEx using a simple loop:

```
string MyRegEx = "";
for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
{
    switch(input[i])
    {
        case 'a':
            MyRegEx += [aâà];
            break;
        case 'c':
            MyRegEx += [cč];
            break;

        ....

        default: //for letters that do not have any accented variants
            MyRegEx += input[i];
            break;
    }
}

System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx R = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx(MyRegEx);
var Your Results = SuggestionsList.Where(s => R.IsMatch(s.ToLower()));
```

Comment: Thanks, the RegEX way actually could be a good one, however I'm totally new with C# or anything Windows whatsoever, could you show some little example or a website with an example of searching a list using REGEX? Thank you very much!

Comment: Added a simple example with skeleton. You'll need to fill up all desired variants in the `switch` part.

Comment: I just realize that now I can't make case insensitive search. Do I really have to add all letter + cases to the regex?
edit: nevermind, added .ToLower() to input...sorry and thanks!

Comment: @majodom: That's fine. You also have the `IgnoreCase` option available  when you create the `RegEx` object. See RegEx constructor for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to compare with a diactriticless version of the string, you can achieve that by using a feature in Unicode string libraries (available in C#) called [normalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx) (String.Normalize). FormD normalization splits a compound character into "base character" and diactrics.

You can use this code snippet to strip a diacritic from a character using normalization:

```
string formDString = txt.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

var sb = new StringBuilder();

var len = formDString.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    var formDChar = formDString[i];

    System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory category = System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(formDChar);

    if (category != System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
    {
        sb.Append(formDChar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like Windows Phone doesn't support text Normalization? There's no string.Normalize available for me, even when using System.Text...

Comment: Check my code sample, you call normalize from a string instance. I wrote String.Normalize so you know that it's a string method