# How to compare strings with case insensitive and accent insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive

How to compare strings with case insensitive and accent insensitive

Alright this is done easily at SQL server

However I would like to do the same at C# .NET 4.5.1.

How can I do that with most proper way?

I mean these 3 strings should return equal when compared

```
http://www.buroteknik.com/metylan-c387c4b0ft-tarafli-bant-12cm-x25mt_154202.html
http://www.buroteknik.com/METYLAN-C387C4B0FT-TARAFLI-BANT-12cm-x25mt_154202.html
http://www.buroteknik.com/METYLAN-C387C4B0FT-TARAFLı-BANT-12cm-x25mt_154202.html
```

I need a method that would say these 2 below are same SQL server says they are equal.

```
 tarafli 
 TARAFLİ
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To ignore both case AND accents, you can use `string.Compare()` with both the `IgnoreNonSpace` AND the `IgnoreCase` options, like so:

```
string s1 = "http://www.buroteknik.com/metylan-c387c4b0ft-tarafli-bant-12cm-x25mt_154202.html";
string s2 = "http://www.buroteknik.com/METYLAN-C387C4B0FT-TARAFLI-BANT-12cm-x25mt_154202.html";
string s3 = "http://www.buroteknik.com/METYLAN-C387C4B0FT-TARAFLı-BANT-12cm-x25mt_154202.html";

Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s2, s3, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

In response to your comments below, this works for `tarafli` and `TARAFLİ` too.

The following code prints 0, **meaning the strings are equal**:

```
string s1 = "tarafli";
string s2 = "TARAFLİ";
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

And here it is using the Turkish culture (I'm guessing at what the correct culture is).
This also prints 0:

```
string s1 = "tarafli";
string s2 = "TARAFLİ";

var trlocale = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(s1, s2, trlocale, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Comment: ok this method failed for these 2 strings : tarafli - TARAFLİ however SQL server says equal as supposed to be

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG What locale are those strings from?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG It works fine when I try it with those strings. I'll put it in my answer.

Comment: I've tried it too and it works for me (I used the invariant culture).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `string.Compare` with the overload which takes the proper `CultureInfo` and `CompareOptions`:

```
string.Compare(s1, s2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace |
                                                   CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Edit:**

As for your question on `CultureInfo`, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190529(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The comparison uses the culture parameter to obtain culture-specific
>   information, such as casing rules and the alphabetical order of
>   individual characters. For example, a particular culture could specify
>   that certain combinations of characters be treated as a single
>   character, that uppercase and lowercase characters be compared in a
>   particular way, or that the sort order of a character depends on the
>   characters that precede or follow it.

Comment: Because you want to be compatible with the culture the user runs on his machine. See my edit.

Comment: thanks for answer again can we say that MS SQL server also uses that information when i set invariant culture and invariant case ?

Comment: What does MSSQL have to do with anything?

Comment: whichever machine it works invariant culture and invariant case so i wondered :D ah i set latin though :D i see now ty

Comment: ok this method failed for these 2 strings : tarafli - TARAFLİ however SQL server says equal as supposed to be

Comment: Example:
string.Compare("citroen","Citroën", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)
0