# How to compare strings at C# like in SQL server case insensitive and accent insensitive

Tags: c#, string-comparison, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive

Alright here 4 words which are equal at SQL server `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI` collation which is case insensitive and accent insensitive

```
taraflı
TaraFLI
TARaFLİ
Tarafli
```

However i could not find a way to compare these as equal at C# .net 4.5.1

Are there any way to make such comparsion like in SQL server ?

I checked this thread as well : [Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

Event RemoveDiacritics method at that thread fails

Comment: @MelanciaUK no solution there try yourself please

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I deleted my answer since it didn't help.

Comment: Dont ask the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This compares all those strings as equal:

```
string.Compare(s1,s2,
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Example

 string.Compare("citroen","Citroën", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase)
 0