# String compare with special characters in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stringcomparer

I have two strings "`CZSczs`" - "`ČŽŠčžš`" and I want to return true when I compare the strings. I tried with string comparison but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
int result = string.Compare("CZSczs", "ČŽŠčžš", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace); 
bool equal = result == 0;
```

As pointed out in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)'s accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the culture :

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string string1 = "CZSczs";
        string string2 = "ČŽŠčžš";

        if(String.Compare(string1, string2, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("same");
        }
        else
        {
        Console.WriteLine("not same");
        }

    }
}
```

See this working code on : [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/No1YIO)