# Text search like SQL COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, collation

I can search customers table without any problems by SQL.

```
select Name
from Customers
where  Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI like '%ozgur%'
```

This query can find "özgür"

When I place this table to cache and try to search this table with linq, I can't find "özgür" by "ozgur" search word.

Is there any similar way to use Latin1_General_CI_AI in C# LINQ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 13.0

Comment: LINQ isn't SQL. It's a query language that sits on top of an ORM. Collation is something that should be configured on the *entity properties* if possible

Comment: @emert117 there's no such version. What ORM are you using? NHibernate? Entity Framework? EF Core? All of them work with LINQ. How did you configure the context and entities?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am using  Entity Framework.

Comment: @emert117 why not modify the column's collation if you want it to work in an accent-insensitive way? Who specified `_AS` anyway? If the current collation is accent insensitive you don't need to change anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can't modify column's collation. DB is large and always in use.

Comment: @emert117 what is the current collation? Is it really accent sensitive (_AS)? Do you really need that collation statement?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos column's collation is Turkish_CI_AS . If I change column's collation, will linq work the way I want? (I will create a temp table and try that.)

Comment: Not with collation, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723053/using-collation-in-linq-to-sql  But it should work with a `string.Compare`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051621/string-compare-with-special-characters-in-c-sharp

Comment: @LocEngineer I already read these questions. I created a temp table  with Latin1_General_CI_AI collation. But Linq didn't work the way I want again :(

Comment: Then you already know the answer: No. Not with COLLATE. Only if you put that in, say, a stored procedure with the search value as a parameter. Or use a custom string comparer with CultureInfo.

Comment: @LocEngineer the OP asks for the correct thing. You *can't* use String.Compare in SQL. And yes, `COLLATE` is the correct option with SQL. No, LINQ to SQL didn't work. It loaded everything in memory then tried to filter the data *locally*.

Comment: @emert117 the only place I've found that uses a collation is [Entity SQL's ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/order-by-entity-sql). You could [use raw SQL with SqlQuery](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) BUT!!! your query's performance will be bad. `LIKE '%...%'` has to scan the entire table without benefit of indexing. Even `WHERE Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI = '%ozgur%'` would have to perform an index scan as indexes are built using specific collations

Comment: @emert117 have you considered using a [full text search index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) to speed up searching for words anywhere in a field? With an FTS index you could write `WHERE CONTAINS(Name ,@thatName)`

Answer (score 2):

The only place I've found that uses a collation is Entity SQL's [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/order-by-entity-sql) clause.

You could use [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) as shown [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx) to use a SQL string (with parameters of course) that uses the COLLATE clause :

```
var query = "select Name from Customers " +
           " where  Name COLLATE Turkish_CI_AI like @name";
var results = myContext.Customers
                       .SqlQuery(query,new SqlParameter("@name","%ozgur%"))
                       .ToList();
```

I'd advise caution though. `LIKE '%...%'` can't benefit from any indexes that cover the `name` field and will have to search the entire table. Even `Name = @name COLLATE ...` may not use any indexes the collation doesn't match the collation the index was built with.

You should consider using [full text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) indexes and make full text search queries for specific words, eg:

```
SELECT Name from Customers WHERE CONTAINS(Name ,@thatName)
```

**Update**

Another option is to use an interceptor to change the SQL generated by a clause, as shown in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644900/134204). That interceptor uses a regular expression to replace `LIKE` with `CONTAINS`. A simpler expression could be used to inject the `COLLATE` clause before `LIKE`

The code isn't trivial, but at least it's an option.

Comment: I have to use `LIKE '%...%'` at SQL DB side . I don't want to run a query on database server. I will try t o write a C# function for calculation of string similarity. If I can't find a good solution at application server side, I will use your advice for a SQL solution .Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @emert117 you *are* running a query on the database in any case. LINQ to EF generates a SQL query that will run on the database. When you write `ctx.Customers.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList()` EF will execute `select name from customers` on the database. What you *don't* want to do is load every customer name from the database and try to filter them on the client. This may work for a few thousand records but not hundreds of thousands or millions of records

Comment: Sorry, I mentioned wrong. I use EF while putting data to cache. I want to search cache without running query on DB.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use following filer clause for unicode values

Converting the collation type will cause performance issues and prevent index usage

```
select Name
from Customers
where Name like N'%özgür%'
```

Comment: I must use application server for search. I don't want to use database for this. So I can't use Full Text Search and SQLquery. I must solve this problem with C#.

Comment: @Eralper although forgetting that `N` can cause problems, it won't fix *this* problem. If the *field's* collation is accent sensitive, the server won't match strings that have different accents, whether a Unicode literal is used or not.

Comment: @emert117 when you use EF you use the database, not an application server

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using a normal query (via context.Database.SqlQuery) that returns an array of ids and use this ids in your linq statement.