# Linq select not working with special character

Tags: linq

I have an issue whereby I use a Linq query to select a person's name from a list, it works perfectly fine until there is a special character in the name, then it fails and I don't know why. I've tried replacing the special characters with nothing, but that doesn't work either

This is my query

```
PersonName = (From Name In AllNames Where importedNames.Name = player.Name) Select importedNames.ID).First.ToString
```

And these are some examples that don't work

- R. Ng’ambi
- M. Lacný

Comment: Shouldn’t it be == in your where clause

Comment: You need to use a string function that is culture sensitive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String compare with special characters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051621/string-compare-with-special-characters-in-c-sharp)