# Ignore accented letters while filtering a string in C#

Tags: c#

In the following block of code,the letters accented are not recognized (i fall into the "else")

```
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           foreach (char c in str) {
              if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_') {
                 sb.Append(c);
              }
              else
              {
               // if c is accented, i arrive here
              }
```

What can i do to ignore accents?
thanks for your help

Comment: can you provide a sample string / expected input / output

Comment: For example, if a letter is accented i want it to be in my stringbuilder!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison

Comment: So if `str` were equal to `ÀÁÂÃÄÅ BBBBBB` you'd still want that entire string, except for the space, to be added to the string builder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using [char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Indicates whether the specified Unicode character is categorized as a letter or a decimal digit.

```
if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == '_') {
    sb.Append(c);
}
```

The functions returns true for any letter, including accented ones.

Answer (score 2):

How about just cleaning up the strings by removing accents and diacritics?

```
public string RemoveAccentsAndDiacritics(string s)
{
    return string.Concat(
        s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
         .Where(c => System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) !=
                     System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what this does? I'm not a *great* .NET developer but I've been using it for a good while. I'd have to go and look up almost everything here; what is `Normalize` or `NormalizationForm` or what exactly is included in `NonSpacingMark`? Compared to sstan's answer this seems remarkably over-engineered and is not very readable. Don't get me wrong, I'm not afraid to go and read documentation on MSDN but for an answer this leaves a lot of guess work up to the question askwer. This is the kind of answer that has a dev writing comments like `//leave this here it works somehow`

Comment: Sure, but the difference being that `ááá` and `ééé` don't yield the same value here. Unicode normalization forms are described [here](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html). Broadly speaking, they're used to compare canonical representations of strings, such that strings like `Aimée` and `Aimee` could be compared meaningfully. FormD does this by removing accents and diacritics. I don't quite think this covers OPs needs, but you might well choose to do this in combination with @sstan 's answer so that less information is lost when you do your string cleaning.

Comment: @sab669 A unicode non-spacing mark is one that modifies the current character rather then one the sits in it's own space. In "typing" terms, the carriage doesn't advance when a non-spacing character is encountered. Stripping `SpacingCombiningMark` chars might be an idea too...