# DataGridView filter ignoring diacritics (accents) on cells, words

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, filter

I use `TextBox` for filtering in `DataGridView` [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxkU7.png). This is work perfect.
Cells of the table contained latin 1250 characters.
I want to make search for ignores accents on words in cells.
Example.
If is textbox `"knjazevacka"`, search results contain `"knjaževačka"`
Sorry for bad english.
This is code for import table:

```
Dim blah As New System.Net.WebClient
blah.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
Dim str As String = blah.DownloadString(urlfiberlTextBox.Text)
Dim Results As DataSet = ConvertHTMLTablesToDataSet(str)
For Each Data As DataTable In Results.Tables
    FiberList.DataSource = Data
Next
```

This is for search:

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = FiberList.DataSource
bs.Filter = String.Format("[Column1] LIKE '*{0}*' OR [Column1] LIKE '*{0}*' OR [Column3] LIKE '*{0}*'", FiberSearchTextBox.Text)
FiberList.DataSource = bs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Option 1**

**Select also Unaccented data from database and use in filter**

If you can change the query of select data, as an option, when selecting data from SQL Server, you can also select unaccented column values and then filter data based on them.

For example, set change your query to contain unaccented values:

```
SELECT Column1, Column1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI AS Column1_UnAccented 
FROM Table1
```

Then, perform filtering using unaccented column values:

```
bindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("Column1_UnAccented LIKE '*{0}*'", textBox1.Text)
```

### **Option 2**

**Make data unaccented using C# and put them in new a column and use in filter**

If you can't change the select query, You can add a new column to the data table and put unaccented data in it using using below method that [Blair Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/3110834) shared, and then filter based on new column:

```
Public Function RemoveDiacritics(text) As String
    Dim normalizedString = text.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormD)
    Dim stringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For Each c In normalizedString
        Dim unicodeCategory = Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)
        If (unicodeCategory <> Globalization.UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) Then
            stringBuilder.Append(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormC)
End Function
```

Comment: It appears his data tables come from the `DownloadString` call.

Comment: I know this solution for remove diacritics. But it is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Which one is not suitable for you? You can use either of above options :) The first one is suitable when you can change the query and the other is suitable when you can't change the query.

Comment: I'm not fully understand option1.  I use DownloadString and ConvertHTMLTablesToDataSet for import data in datageradview. Add new column with unaccented data is a problem for me.

Comment: Option 1 is suitable when you have access to the select query that provides your data. In your case that you are using `ConvertHTMLTablesToDataSet` it seems Option 2 is suitable for you.

Comment: Why you can't add a new column to table?

Comment: Yes, Making the column invisible is the thing that you should perform on `DataGridView`.  for example `Me.DataGridView1.Columns(10).Visible=False`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the `Filter` or the `DataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter` property one way you can do this is if you convert each column that has diacritics into strings that remove them.

For example:

```cs
var searchText = RemoveDiacritics(this.textBox1.Text);
var table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Zgrada", typeof(string));

// sample data
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 105");
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 147 ulaz II");
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 147 ulaz III");
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 152");
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 154");
table.Rows.Add("Knjaževačka 158/II");

// add the equivalent converted column
table.Columns.Add("ZgradaNormalized", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    row.SetField("ZgradaNormalized", RemoveDiacritics(row.Field<string>("Zgrada")));

table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[ZgradaNormalized] LIKE '%{0}%'", searchText);
```

Using this method to remove diacritics pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison).

```cs
static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
    return string.Concat(
        text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
        .Where(ch => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch) !=
                                      UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
      ).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```