# C# DataGridView.DefaultView.RowFilter with charlist

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, filter, rowfilter

I want to filter my datagrid with [charlist] like sql statement.

let's say I am searching for "çiçek" in PlantName. My sql select was like;

```
SELECT * FROM Plants WHERE PlantName LIKE %[cç][ıi][cç]ek%
```

and this was returning;

```
çiçek
cicek
cıcek
çıçek
etc....
```

how can I do this for DataGridView.DefaultView.RowFilter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView filter ignoring diacritics (accents) on cells, words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340371/datagridview-filter-ignoring-diacritics-accents-on-cells-words)

Comment: Hello brother, thanks for your quick reply. I tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/249126/5700467 it's ok for [ıi] but I have 5 more letters. they are [cç], [gğ], [oö], [sş], [uü] it doesn't work for this letters.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way;

first of all you have to create a search index. for example we have a Plants table and it has a PlantName field. Just populate a new field of **PlantName** and apply a replace operation for tricky letters.

DataBase side;

Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(**PlantName**,'ç','C'),'Ç','C'),'i','I'),'ı','I'),'İ','I'),'ğ','G'),'Ğ','G'),'ö','O'),'Ö','O'),'ş','S'),'Ş','S'),'ü','U'),'Ü','U'),'-',' ') AS **SEARCH_INDEX**

C# side;

```
private string mReplace(string txt)
    {
        string sonuc;
        if (txt == null) { return ""; }
        txt = txt.Replace(" ", " ");
        txt = txt.Replace("-", " ");
        txt = txt.Replace("ç", "C");
        txt = txt.Replace("Ç", "C");
        txt = txt.Replace("ı", "I");
        txt = txt.Replace("i", "I");
        txt = txt.Replace("İ", "I");
        txt = txt.Replace("ğ", "G");
        txt = txt.Replace("Ğ", "G");
        txt = txt.Replace("ö", "O");
        txt = txt.Replace("Ö", "O");
        txt = txt.Replace("ş", "S");
        txt = txt.Replace("Ş", "S");
        txt = txt.Replace("ü", "U");
        txt = txt.Replace("Ü", "U");
        sonuc = txt.ToUpper();
        return sonuc;
    }
```

use this function at your search line, like;

```
DataTable1.DefaultView.RowFilter = "SEARCH_INDEX LIKE '*" + mReplace(txtPlantName.Text) + "*'";
```

http://mehmetgoldenhead.blogspot.com.tr/2017/05/ms-acces-icin-turkce-karakter-replace.html