# Powershell hash table and duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, powershell, hashtable, collation

I am using a hash table to store some names and ids in Greek characters.

```
    $hsNames = @{}
    $hsNameID = 1

    $name = "Νικος"

    $hsNames.Add($name, $hsNameID)
    $hsNameID++

    $name = "Νίκος"
    $hsNames.Add($name, $hsNameID)

    $hsNames
```

The output of the above is:

```
Name                           Value      
----                           -----    
Νικος                          1                                              
Νίκος                          2
```

This means that two keys were created for the same name when there is a greek accent in one of them. Now I do not want this to happen, I need to have only one key with the 1st ID (1)- the behavior of utf8_unicode_ci in MySQL. I guess I need to somehow tell powershell to use the Unicode Collation Algorithm (http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/tr10-33.html) in string comparisons. But how?

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, even though one could argue that the two names are different *because of* the accents. You have to decide whether to store the original spelling and "normalized" spelling, or just the normalized spelling as the conversion is a one-way process.

I found two links that provide a method to arrive at a solution.
[Ignoring accented letters in string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison) and the [PowerShell version of this same C# code](http://www.lazywinadmin.com/2015/05/powershell-remove-diacritics-accents.html).

Using the PowerShell script in the ISE, I was able to write the following:

```
$hsNames = @{}
$hsNameID = 1

$name1 = "Νικος"

$hsNames.Add($name1, $hsNameID)
$hsNameID++

$name2 = "Νίκος"
$hsNames.Add($name2, $hsNameID)

$hsNames

$new1 = Remove-StringDiacritic $name1
$new2 = Remove-StringDiacritic $name2

"With Diacritic removed"
$new1
$new2
$new1 -eq $new2
```

and the output was:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                 
Νικος                          1                                                                                                                                     
Νίκος                          2                                                                                                                                     
With Diacritic removed
Νικος
Νικος
True
```

Based on this, you can "normalize" your strings before inserting in your hash table, and you will end up with a single Key instead of two that you desire.

Comment: Yes I found out about this "normalization" after I posted the question. A major problem is the performance of Remove-StringDiacritic function. The csv data contains more than 100.000.000 rows and I have two string fields in each row. Some first tests showed a slowed down import process by 80%. So, I will not normalize the strings **before** entering them as I initially did, but use the normalized strings as values in the hashtable only if the original does not already exist...

Comment: Also I am worried whether this normalization will cover everything utf8_unicode_ci does, but I have to give it a try.