# Sql Linq search query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I having and issue with a sql linq query that I have. I have a query that when you type a person name in an input text box I have to show a list of persons that contain that name, but the problem that I am having is the following:
a person name can look like so **jose** ou **josé**. It's the same name but one with **é** an the other without **é**. My query

```
var person = (from p in context.Person
              where p.Name.Contains(personName) || p.Name.StartsWith(personName) || p.Name.EndsWith(personName)                            
                          select p).OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(page, 10);
   return person;
```

The Idea is to when I wright jose the query get all the people that have jose and josé and vice versa. If I wright jose the query only returns people that have jose in there name and does not allsow return people that have josé with the é. Does any one know how I can ressolve this issue. Thank you

Comment: Btw, `p.Name.Contains(personName)` handles `StartsWith` and `EndsWidth` so no need of them. What about your main question, from the database point of view the names in example are different.

Comment: Hello, The name are the same but one has é an the other does not. I have to return the name that have é or do not have é. Thank

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), usage in current culture would look like this (if you do not wish to use your current culture, then you could simply use `InvariantCulture` instead):

```
if (String.Compare("Jose", "José", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0)
{
    // both strings are equal
}
```

You would have to implement this check directly into your linq query like this:

```
var person = (from p in context.Person
              where String.Compare(p.Name, personName, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0                        
                          select p).OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToPagedList(page, 10);
return person;
```

This is all very well explained in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359827/ignoring-accented-letters-in-string-comparison)

Comment: Hello I have tried your query but it does not return notyhing.

Comment: Try and debug the query and look what really happens, I cant help you without any context.

Comment: It translates to simple WHERE [t0].[Name] = @p0 with linq2sql, effectively ignoring all the options of Compare.