# How to compare l and ł (Polish character) in c# to return true

Tags: c#, string-comparison, equality

I am trying to compare the following two characters l and ł and get c# to return true

i.e. I have the word Przesyłka and would like to do a string comparison to Przesylka

I have tried the following but they all return false

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("l".Equals("ł", StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
    Console.WriteLine("l".Equals("ł", StringComparison.Ordinal));
    Console.WriteLine("l".Equals("ł", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    Console.WriteLine("l".Equals("ł", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    Console.WriteLine("l".Equals(RemoveDiacritics("ł"), StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/368850/2987066
static string RemoveDiacritics(string text)
{
  return string.Concat( 
      text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
      .Where(ch => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(ch)!=
                                    UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
    ).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

As you can see I also tried a workarond from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/368850/2987066) but it also returned false.

Is there a way to compare these two characters in c# in a way that returns true?

Comment: Use the *correct* culture instead of `Invariant` or `Ordinal`. If your application runs in a Polish locale, you don't need to specify anything

Comment: Are  l and ł equal in Polish to begin with? If not, no CultureInfo will produce the result you want. From Wikipedia `The Polish ⟨Ł⟩ now sounds the same as the English ⟨W⟩`

Comment: I've just tried this with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");` and then `Console.WriteLine("l".Equals("ł", StringComparison.CurrentCulture));`but unfortunately still didnt work

Comment: Why do you *expect* these to be equal? This isn't an L with diacritics, it's a different letter with a different sound

Comment: I have just checked with a Polish speaker and you are 100% correct.. these are completely different letters

Comment: `RemoveDiacritics` won't work because `ł` can not be split into `l` + some (probably non-existing) accent symbol, like `è = e + ◌̀`. So the best approach here would be to write a custom comparison and/or normalization function. And even though Ł may sound closer to english W, treating L as Ł may still make sense.

Comment: @JKennedy what are you trying to do ?  This sounds like transliteration. There are relevant SO questions and probably NuGet libraries as well

Comment: I'm using [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bi2zBM) to normalize them

Comment: Just to reiterate a comment to one of the answers below: If you search this page for `Przesyłka` in your browser you'll find that it also matches `Przesylka` - so this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
string.Compare("l", "ł", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace) == 0;
```

> [IgnoreNonSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=net-8.0): Indicates that the string comparison must ignore nonspacing combining characters, such as diacritics.

Comment: These are different letters, not `l` with diacritics. Using Latin1 will mangle the text

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but it returns 0 for me. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q6R2Nu When I search `l` in this page, the browser also matches `ł`, so I think it is considered as `l` with diacritics.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that `ą` and `ą` may look identical, but they are created differently. `ą` is U+0105, which is a single character; however, `ą` is combined using two characters: U+0061 and U+0328. Despite `ł` looking like `l` with a stroke, I cannot find the stroke character to combine with it. By copying and pasting `ł` from the original question, I noticed the character `ł` in the original question is U+0142, which is different from `l`, which is U+006C.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not the best solution, but if you really need to have this to be equal you could write a custom string EqualityComparer:

```cs
var equalsComparer = new EqualsComparer();
if (equalsComparer.Equals("Przesyłka", "Przesylka"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("true");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("false");
}


class EqualsComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string? x, string? y)
    {
        x = x.Replace("ł", "L").ToLowerInvariant();
        y = y.Replace("ł", "L").ToLowerInvariant();

        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work. It's the only solution I think would work, but it's not pretty to say the least

Comment: @JKennedy - `It's the only solution I think would work...` maybe you should explain in more detail, why you believe this is the only valid solution. shingo's answer also works and is way prettier.

Comment: oh yea true. I didnt see that solution when I wrote it. Yes you are correct Shingo's solution also works